# Do you accept questions of the type "does x type of mod exist for game y?"

Tags: support

Here is a look at the question I would like to ask but I am not sure about its acceptance here:

Do any single player style mods exist for Unreal tournament 2004, I am looking for a bit more than bot match or the built in single player mode but there is so much out there for this game, I am having a hard time pinning one down.

I understand that there will not be a full blown campaign but something focused on a more content for solo players.

any suggestions?

Comment: while they aren't allowed like frank said below, you could drop by in chat and ask if anyone knows about such a thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, we do not.  We don't do recommendations, which is what your question is asking.  We classify recommendations as anything that asks us to find something (like software, hardware, whatever) that matches specific criteria.  Those questions are entirely off-topic.

Just to nip it in the bud, I've had arguments in the past where someone is just asking for the existence of something.  That is still a recommendation, as asking if something exists carries the implication of listing whatever it is that exists.  Not to mention that just answering the base question with a yes or no is a rather terrible answer, and isn't helpful to anyone at all.  Nor does it meet the character limit required to actually answer the question.

So in short, no, we don't accept those types of questions.

Comment: That's what I thought, many sites are the same way about this kind of thing. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: even more on questions like this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad/185482